# How to display Sparklyr table in a clean readable format similar to the output of display() in Databricks?

Tags: r, dataframe, databricks, sparklyr

There exist a Databricks’s built-in display() function (see documentation [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/13/introducing-r-notebooks-in-databricks.html)) which allow users to display R or SparkR dataframe in a clean and human readable manner where user can scroll to see all the columns and perform sorting on the columns. See image below:

[image]

Is there a way to display tables that are output from sparklyr in such a manner in Databricks? Obviously I am not able to use function directly on the sparklyr table hence I attempted to convert the sparklyr table into a R dataframe before using display() function but was hit with *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type N* error.

[image]